# Markov's Inequality Intuition

Tags: probability-theory

$Pr(X\geq a) < \frac{E[X]}{a}$

- i) if $a \leq E[X]$ , then our result is $Pr(X\geq a) < x$ and depending on the value of $a, x \geq 1$
- ii) if $a > E[X]$ , then our result is $Pr(X\geq a) < x$ and depending on the value of $a, x < 1$

How do we interpret this bound, is it in terms of standard deviations or actual probabilities? If it is probabilities, then how can $Pr(X\geq a) < 1.2$ be interpreted? Thank you!

Comment: First, it should be $E[X]$, not $E[x]$. Second, what is [little] $x$ in i) and ii)? Also, $\operatorname{Pr}(X \ge a)$ is a probability so it is always $\le 1$.

Comment: @angryavian I am going to edit that. [little] $x$ is the value that $Pr(X \geq a)$ is going to be bounded by depending on the value of $a$. I was wondering how $Pr(X \geq a)$ could be bounded by a number greater than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E[X]/a > 1$, then the bound gives you no new information, since you already know that the probability is bounded by $1$. Therefore, the inequality is only useful when $a>E[X]$.

Comment: words of wisdom that makes perfect sense!